# How to cron a php with siteurl?

Tags: php, cron

Suppose I have a `send.php` file, which include a function to get the site's URL (for example, unsubscribe an email), but the emails are auto-send by a cron command, it seems in this case the siteurl will not work properly, since local script has no URL at all?

Of course I can set the right URL exactly in the `send.php`, but if I don't want to do this, is there any solution?

**EDIT**

```
//siteurl in send.php
function siteURL(){
        $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
        $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        return $protocol.$domainName;
}
```

**cron**

```
#cron to excude send.php
 */1 * *  *  * /usr/bin/php  /pathto/send.php
```

Comment: Post the code you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the URL to the cron script, for example as environment variable or CLI argument:

```
*/1 * *  *  * SITE_URL=example.com /usr/bin/php  /pathto/send.php
# or
*/1 * *  *  * /usr/bin/php /pathto/send.php example.com
```

In the script:

```
$siteURL = getenv('SITE_URL');
// or
$siteURL = $argv[1];
```

That's a better alternative to a) exposing your cron script publicly through the web server and b) going the long way round through an HTTP request for something that doesn't need it.

Comment: Pff... copy and paste... ;)

Comment: @deceze shall add `http://`? since the url at last shall be accessible to the user.

Comment: @van Add whatever you need. :)

Comment: @deceze I think I need to add them as `SI='http://example.com'` right? what's more, maybe `php -f` were better thatn `php` right?

Comment: `php -f file` is the same as `php file`; that environment variable looks OK to me.

Comment: @deceze what's wrong? `/bin/sh: usr/bin/php: No such file or directory`

Comment: Missing leading `/` maybe?

Comment: @deceze sorry, still not work, googled some add `-q` to `php`, what's mean? I can't find it by `php -h`

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl` or `wget` with full url.

e.g.:

```
* * * * * wget http://example.com/send.php
```

or:

```
* * * * * curl http://example.com/send.php
```

**UPDATE**

Here are some differences: [curl vs Wget](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html)

Btw, I also use `fetch` that lacks most of the options the above two have, but is native to my favorite OS and does exactly the same job when it comes to download a single page.

Comment: what's the difference? In which case I shall try `wget`?

Comment: Choose whatever you have currently installed on the OS or select according to your personal preferences. With curl you could make HEAD requests, but I doubt you need that right now, so it doesn't really matter.